# Bluetooth unavailable on android studio virtual device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, bluetooth, android-emulator

"I am currently working on integrating Bluetooth connectivity into a Flutter application. However, when I attempt to run the code, I encounter an error indicating that my virtual device does not support Bluetooth. This issue is preventing me from successfully establishing a Bluetooth connection. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this compatibility issue with my virtual device."

I searched online and I found that android emulator does not support Bluetooth (android studio had no access to system hardware).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.